# Calling a form through another form (button)

Tags: php, forms

I'm trying to add into DB some info through a form called after pressing a button which is also part of a form. More exactly, after pressing the button, a form is printed, like this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['x']))
{
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $msg=mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['msg']);

        mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO user_posts (msg) VALUES ('$msg')");
    }
?>
    <form method="post">
        <textarea name="msg" cols="100" rows="10"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
<?php
}


?>
    <form method="post">
        <button type="submit" name="x">Press this!</button>
    </form>
```

After I press POST['x'], the form with textarea appears as intended, but if i press "POST[submit]", the page shows the first button only and i can't figure why no info is added to the DB. I don't see what is wrong with my logic... A little guidance would be most welcome! Thank you in advance!

Comment: In that isset($_POST['x'] is not set so outer most if condition fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you submit the form, the POST data will be sent to the same page again, and since the if statement to add the DATA to the database is inside your first if, it won't get sent.

First check if the second form is sent, if not check for the X button.

This is the solution:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $msg=mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['msg']);

    mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO user_posts (msg) VALUES ('$msg')");
}
if(isset($_POST['x'])) {
    ?>
    <form method="post">
        <textarea name="msg" cols="100" rows="10"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
    <?php
}
?>
<form method="post">
    <button type="submit" name="x">Press this!</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must create an single one form :

```
<form method="post">
    <textarea name="msg" cols="100" rows="10"></textarea>
    <button type="submit" name="x">Press this!</button>
</form>
```

With this, your button named **x** will be send.
You must also remove the **if** statement :

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
```

You should'nt verify two buttons posts.

Comment: this would be logic and simple, yes, but i want to know how to make it work in the form i presented the exercise. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

The logic error is that you test for the submission of 1 variable `x` and then within that you then test for the second posted var `submit`. Try changing the above such as:

```
<?php
    if( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ){
        /* db logic */
        $msg=mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['msg']);
        mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO user_posts (msg) VALUES ('$msg')");  
    }
    if( isset( $_POST['x'] ) ){
        /* display the second form */
        echo '
        <form method="post">
            <textarea name="msg" cols="100" rows="10"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </form>';
    }
?>

<form method="post">
    <button type="submit" name="x">Press this!</button>
</form>
```